# Calculating specific lottery winning odds

Tags: combinatorics

In the lottery of, you select 6 out of 34 numbers.

Also, you can send a ticket with up to **8 different combinations** (that are automatically generated).

Starting from 3 correct number guesses you could win money back.

I am interested in understanding how to calculate the odds of getting ***at least*** 3 correct matches.

That means - if i send a lottery ticket with 8 lines of 6 selected numbers, what are the odds of me getting 3,4,5,6 correct matches?

Comment: Might be easier to compute the probabilities of 0, 1, 2 matches, and subtract the answer from 1.

Comment: thought of that, but i still can't figure out the correct calculation.

Comment: Well, let's start simple: with just one line of 6 numbers, what is the probability of no matches?

Comment: I am not sure, is it the probability of me choosing 6 out of (34 - 6) - meaning - making all the wrong choices, counting out the correct numbers?

Comment: Well, it's the number of ways of making all wrong choices, divided by the number of ways of making choices. Equivalently, it the probability the first choice is wrong, times the probability the second choice is wrong, etc.

Comment: $28\choose6$ would be the number of ways to get 0 matches as you'd want to have only items from the 28 non-selected numbers.  For a match of 1 number, you'd take $6\choose1$$X$$28\choose5$ since you are wanting 5 non-winning numbers and 1 of the 6 winning numbers.  Do you understand the "n Choose r" notation and calculation?

Comment: @JBKing yes i know about n choose k and how to calculate it.